# Rspec integral factories in test

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I apologize if my English is not perfect but it is not my native language.
I have to test a MySql database with Rails 4.2, Rspec 3.3 and FactoryGirl 4.5.
The tests of base models are green. The problems comes when I have to test a model that contains foreign keys that can't be duplicated.
At first I have two models (*dimension.rb* through *feature.rb* and *technical.rb*) each having a foreign key that comes from the same model (*current.rb*):

```
 #models/dimension.rb
 class Dimension < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :current
    has_many :features
    ...
 end

#models/feature.rb
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base 
   belongs_to :dimension
   has_many :bxes
   ...
end

#models/technical.rb
class Technical < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :current
   has_many :bxes
   ...
end
```

These two models are placed in the final model (*bxe.rb*)

```
#models/bxe.rb
class Bxe < ActiveRecord::Base 
 belongs_to :feature
 belongs_to :technical
 ...
 validates  :technical_id, presence: true
 validates  :feature_id, presence: true 
end
```

The Current model is:

```
#models/current.rb
 class Current < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :technicals
   has_many :dimensions
   validates :current, presence: true, uniqueness: true
   validates :value,   presence: true, uniqueness: true
 end
```

The factories are the following:

```
#spec/factories/current.rb
 FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :current do   
   trait :lower do
    current '800A'
    value 800
   end
   trait :higher do
    current '2000A'
    value 2000
   end    
 end
end

#spec/factories/dimension.rb
FactoryGirl.define do 
 factory :dimension do
  ...
  trait :one do
    current {create(:current, :lower)}
  end     
  trait :two do
    current {create(:current, :higher)}
  end     
 end
end

#spec/factories/feature.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :feature do  
  descr 'MyString'
  dimension { create(:dimension, :one) } 
  ...
 end 
end

#spec/factories/technical.rb
FactoryGirl.define do  
 factory :technical do
  ...  
  trait :A do
    current { create(:current, :lower) }
  end
  trait :L do
    current { create(:current, :higher) }
  end         
 end
end

#spec/factories/bxes.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :bxe do
   ...
   technical {create(:technical, :A) }
   feature
  end
end
```

When I run the test on the models the first command (*technical*) runs and the factory creates a Current record  with id = 1 but the second (*features*) fails, since the factory try again to create the record of Current with the same data, action prohibited from the model *current.rb*

```
#rspec spec/models
2.1.2 :001 > FactoryGirl.create(:bxebusbar, :one)
 ...  Current Exists ... SELECT  1 AS one FROM `currents` WHERE `currents`.`current` = BINARY '800A' LIMIT 1
 ...  INSERT INTO `currents` (`current`, `value`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('800A', 800, ..., ...)
...  INSERT INTO `technicals` (..., `current_id`, ..., `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (..., 1, ..., ...)
...  Current Exists ...  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `currents` WHERE `currents`.`current` = BINARY '800A' LIMIT 1
...  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Current has already been taken, Value has already been taken
```

I think that the problem can be solved by creating once only Current record and then using it in the *technical* and *features* factories, what would happen in reality, but I do not know how to do that.
Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sequences](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences) to generate values that will not be duplicated. Another option is to use DatabaseCleaner and setup it to clean database after each test.

With first option:

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :current do   
   trait :lower do
    sequence :current do { |n| "#{n}A" }
    sequence :value do {|n| "#{n}" }
   end    
 end
end
```

Or to setup DataBase Cleaner: [Database cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That solved the problem of testing. However, I would not have two different records for the current. In fact the object BXE comes from two tables that are tied to the same foreign key (_current_). If this is not possible I think I will revise the database relationships

Comment: Then simply use Database Cleaner and configure cleaning around each test suite. Then the object will be re-created every time you enter new test.